# What is the difference of user_online presence & friends_online_presence?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I successfully got my friends' online chat status but I'm confused because I used the user_online_presence permission and not the friends_online_presence permission. Plus, I noticed that when using friends_online_presence permission, my chat status is online but if I use user_online_presence, my chat status is offline.